# C++/ Arduino TCP Packet into byte arr & Struct union

Tags: c++, tcp, unions

I have a union datatype that i want to use to convert a TCP packet form bytes to a few different datatype sizes.

This program works okay with bytes but when It comes to multiple byte variables the order of the bytes are reversed. ex

say the value of the two bytes are 00 01. and loaded into the byte arr. The short that shares the memory interprets 00 01 as 01 00, resulting in a value of 256.

currently the only thing I can think to do is to swap the array position values after they are loaded from the Udp.read. That seems a little silly tho, is there a better way, a magic function that can solve my problems?

```
//the packet: 00 00 00 00 00 06 01 03 00 00 00 01 

// UDT/Struct for handling InputPackets
typedef struct InputPacketStruct{
short Transaction;
short Protocol;
short Length;
byte UnitID;
byte Function;
short Address;
short Quantity;
};

//define union, Pair Struct with byte arr
const int InputStruct_Size = sizeof(InputPacketStruct);

typedef union InputPacketUnion {
    InputPacketStruct Entity;
    byte Bytes[InputStruct_Size -1];
};

// Declare a variable as union 
InputPacketUnion InputPacket;

// ------- Store packet Bytes ------- 
    Udp.read(InputPacket.Bytes,packetSize);     
    Serial.print("Packet contents: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < packetSize; i++) {
      Serial.print(InputPacket.Bytes[i],DEC);
      Serial.print(" ");
    };
 
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Transaction Identifier: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Transaction,DEC); 
    Serial.print("Protocol Identifier: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Protocol,DEC);        
    Serial.print("Length: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Length,DEC);        
    Serial.print("Unit Identifier: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.UnitID,DEC);
    Serial.print("Function Code: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Function,DEC);
    Serial.print("Starting Address: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Address,DEC);     
    Serial.print("Quantity: ");
    Serial.println(InputPacket.Entity.Quantity,DEC);
    Serial.println("");
```

Comment: It is entirely normal and expected to have to translate between host and network byte order. See [`ntohs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) *et al*

Comment: oh thaks! that looks like exactly what im looking for. However Im not able to inclued  the <arpa/inet.h> libary. iv never added a libary  before. is this the correct one? [link](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/inet.h)

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Arduino. A quick search turned up [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/def.h). Looks promisin.